# Laravel 4 - Update many to many

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am currently trying to amend an update page which features a many to many relationship. It updates to my database perfectly, however all I'm trying to achieve now is to actually show the already selected items in my multiple select list in my view.

It currently just shows the entire list of oilgas jobs, just not the currently selected ones which should come from the query in some way.

So, it currently looks like this:

[image]

I need it to look like this, if Instrument Technician was previously chosen.

[image]

The associated files are as follows:

MODELS

OilGasJob.php

```
<?php 

class OilGasJob extends \Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'oilgasjobs';

     public function industryjobs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('IndustryJob');
    }


}
```

IndustryJob.php

```
<?php 

class IndustryJob extends \Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'industryjobs';


     public function oilgasjobs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('OilGasJob');
    }


}
```

CONTROLLER  (CREATE PAGE AND STORE)

```
    public function edit($id)
    {

        $industryjob = IndustryJob::find($id);

        if(is_null($id))
        {
            return Redirect::to('/admin/industry-jobs')->with('message', 'This division job is not valid');
        }

        View::share('page_title', 'Edit Division Job');

        return View::make('admin/industry-jobs/edit')->with('industryjob',$industryjob);

    } 

    public function update($id)

    {

        $rules = array(
                'job_title' => 'Required|Min:3|Max:80'
        );

        $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        If ($validation->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validation);
        } else {

        $industryjob = IndustryJob::find($id);

        if(is_null($id))
        {
            return Redirect::to('/admin/industry-jobs')->with('message', 'This divison job is not valid');
        }

        View::share('page_title', 'Edit Division Job');

        $industryjob->job_title = Input::get('job_title');
        $industryjob->slug    = Str::slug(Input::get('job_title'));
        $industryjob->job_description    = Input::get('job_description');
        $industryjob->job_qualifications    = Input::get('job_qualifications');

        $industryjob->save();

        $industryjob->oilgasjobs()->sync(Input::get('oilgasjobs'));

        return Redirect::to('/admin/industry-jobs')->with('message', 'Division Job updated successfully');
        }

    }
```

VIEW

```
 {{ Form::open(array('url' => URL::to('admin/industry-jobs/edit/'.$industryjob->id), 'class'=>'form-horizontal', 'method' => 'POST')) }}

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="industry_name">Job Title (*)</label>

            <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="job_title" id="job_title" value="{{ $industryjob->job_title }}" />
                </div>
            </div>



      <!-- Industry Type  -->
       <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="body">Related Jobs in Oil & Gas</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
        <select name="oilgasjobs[]" id="oilgasjobs[]" size="6" class="form-control" multiple>
            @foreach(OilGasJob::orderBy('job_title', 'ASC')->get() as $oilgasjob)
                <option value="{{ $oilgasjob->id }}" >{{ $oilgasjob->job_title }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./ Industry Type -->



    <!-- Form Actions -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update Job</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./ form actions -->


{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `edit` method add this code:

```
// ...
$linkedOilgasjob = DB::table('oilgasjob_industryjob')->lists('oilgasjob_id');
return View::make('admin/industry-jobs/edit'
                  ,compact('industryjob')
                  ,compact('linkedOilgasjob'));
```

Then in your view

```
<option value="{{ $oilgasjob->id }}" {{ in_array($oilgasjob->id,linkedOilgasjob) ? "selected='selected'" : "" }} >
    {{ $oilgasjob->job_title }}
</option>
```

Comment: thank you for your input. I've managed to get a solution (see above answer)

Answer (score 0):

CONTROLLER

```
public function edit($id)
    {

        $data['industryjob'] = IndustryJob::find($id);

        $data['oilgasjobs'] = DB::table('industry_job_oil_gas_job')->where('industry_job_id','=',$id)->lists('oil_gas_job_id');

        if(is_null($id))
        {
            return Redirect::to('/admin/industry-jobs')->with('message', 'This division job is not valid');
        }

        View::share('page_title', 'Edit Division Job');

        return View::make('admin/industry-jobs/edit', $data);

    }
```

VIEW

```
<select name="oilgasjobs[]" id="oilgasjobs[]" size="6" class="form-control" multiple>
      @foreach(OilGasJob::orderBy('job_title', 'ASC')->get() as $oilgasjob)
       <?php
        $selected = "";
            if(in_array($oilgasjob->id, $oilgasjobs)) 
            $selected = "selected";         
       ?>
      <option value="{{ $oilgasjob->id }}" <?php echo $selected; ?>>{{ $oilgasjob->job_title }}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>
```